# Windows Mobile Development - Portable Programming?

Tags: windows-mobile, devtools

I want to start developing for Windows Mobile Devices, as I plan to buy one next week. (pay day)

So far most of my PDA experience is with Palm OS (m100, m105, Zire 71 and T3). For Palm there are a few good utilities for programming, mainly [PocketC](http://www.orbworks.com/pcpalm/index.html) and [OnboardC](http://onboardc.sourceforge.net/). These let you program and test on the road. I would use PocketC quite a bit for testing and prototyping, before coding the full app on my PC.

Now the question is are there any equivalents for Windows Mobile, that will let me compile/interpret code on the phone?

Thank you

P.S. I'm aware of PocketC CE, which is no longer supported, and PythonCE, though I would prefer something that is still supported and is or like C or C++.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I should have stated that I'm on a budget, NSBasic seems good, but at $149.99 it's nearly the price of the device. The only other issue is that it's BASIC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmmm.. So you really want to develop on the device? Why?

Anyway, Here are your options:

- [Pocket GCC](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=96949)
- [Pocket C# compiler](http://weblogs.asp.net/pleloup/archive/2004/06/09/151853.aspx)
- [Ruby on Windows Mobile](http://andryshuzain.com/journal/ruby-on-windows-mobile-5) & [Supporting Article](http://andryshuzain.com/journal/ruby-on-windows-mobile-5)
- [PythonCE](http://pythonce.sourceforge.net/)
- [PocketC for Windows CE](http://www.orbworks.com/pcce/index.html)

I know you mentioned PythonCE & Pocket C. But added for comprehension :)

Comment: I have my best Ideas when I'm far away from a machine. I did a large amount of my testing and development on my Palm during uni. As my Palm has had it, I've invested in a HTV Touch Dual (Window Mobile 6), and would like to do the same on it as my palm.

Answer (score 1):

How about NSBASIC?  Their product page (http://www.nsbasic.com/ce/) says you can develop on the device, but I only have personal experience with the Palm version where I didn't need to develop anywhere other than the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

NS Basic/CE allows you to program on the device. It has a built in screen designer and a simple debugger. The language itself is VBScript (a subset of VB), with extensions for Windows Mobile. It also supports external dll's for SQLite, Winsock and lots more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would do what you want, but there's also [MortScript](http://www.sto-helit.de/index.php?module=page&entry=ms_overview&action=view).